# Visual Studio Source not available/ code not running error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the following error while debugging the source code in Visual Studio 2013 edition. I have tried all the solutions present over the stackoverflow, but didn't get the success. I have also repaired and uninstalled/again reinstalled the Visual Studio 2013 but still gets the same error while debugging the code. I am unable to stop at the breakpoint during debugging. Can somebody please help in this?[image: Visual Studio error screen]